# Mounting google collab with google drive

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write `from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')` in **colab cell** but i don't know where it is in Colaboratory?

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the mount drive option instead.[image: Screenshot of Colab]